# How to Install Hibernate In Eclipse kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-kepler

I want to start learning about hibernate, but I don't know how to configure Hibernate in Eclipse.

Please could you provide instructions for configuring Hibernate in Eclipse.

Comment: Did you try to google about the same ?

Comment: yup bro,  but not for eclipse kepler..

Answer (score 2):

Try this out and you will get it configured

http://kaanmutlu.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/hibernate-installationsetup-on-eclipse-ide/

Comment: Here is the link @Hichamov is trying to give                                                           https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

This should help : [HERE YOU WILL FIND THE TUTORIAL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html)

You don't need a hibernate install on eclipse but a hibernate configuration on a Java project

Comment: But How To Congrigure In java Project?

Comment: Read the post man ... ! (Ok: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html)